# responsive calendar schedule

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm looking for a (wordpress) plugin or code that allows my client to approve requests by users using a responsive calendar widget (and a form with both mandatory and optional fields, all combined in 1 code if possible).
I did find quite a good example on http://wpbookingcalendar.com/ but need a few more controls.
My client needs to be booked in 3 time-spans a day (morning, noon & afternoon), and had 2 main types of jobs which he likes to plan himself ahead. Example: week 1 & 2, he only wants to be booked for type A-jobs, week 3 he only want type B-jobs. Once a user has requested a booking, my client needs to approve the request before it is published online. A timeslot that has been approved, can no longer be selected by a user.

If there's anyone who can help me out, that'd be great!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Main reason is that I don't know if I should write code myself, or buy a plugin, which I might not be able to alter to my needs...